# PHP load array values from file and return them as array

Tags: php, arrays, include

I have file:

**en.php**

```
<?php
$lang['word'] = 'word';
$lang['text'] = 'text';
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
function load($file) {
    include $file . '.php';
    echo $lang['word'];
    echo $lang['text'];
}

load('en');
```

### Question:

How to **get array values** from *en.php* and **return them as array** with *load()*.

How to process file to return each array value in load() to use it in index.php like this:

```
   echo $lang['word'];
```

*I know that include function view file in global scope but variables are in local scope. There for I am looking in "return as array" solution.*

Edit:
I want to separate languagse in files **en.php**, **de.php**, **ru.php** ... and then load them into index.php with load. Then retrieve them and echo as `$lang['text']`.

Comment: You can't access those variables because they're out of scope - start using OOP.

Comment: @Stanyer I am open to OOP solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ing. Michal Hudak

Your code is correct

```
<?php
function load($file) {
    include $file . '.php';
    return $lang;
}

print_r(load('en'));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do a `return $lang` in your en.php file and then assign it to a variable in the load function: `$load = include $file . '.php';`

Answer (score 0):

en.php (or lang_en.php)

```
<?php
    class lang_en {
        var $lang = array();
        public function __construct() {
            $this->lang['word'] = 'word';
            $this->lang['text'] = 'text';
        }
        public function get_lang() {
            return $this->lang;
        }
    }
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
    function load($file) {
        include $file . '.php';
        $class_name     = 'lang_' . $file;
        $lang_instance  = new $class_name();
        $get_lang       = $lang_instance->get_lang();
        echo $get_lang['word'];
        echo $get_lang['text'];
    }
    load('en');
?>
```

Untested & it's early - but this should work...

Comment: I want to separate language strings into files en.php, ru.php. And then load them from those files with function in index.php.

Comment: Which is what the answer does. The only difference is the file name is prefixed with `lang_`

Comment: en.php should have only database of strings, then load them from file with function

Answer (score 0):

you are including the file en.php inside the function so `$lang` is local for the function and you can use them directly.

```
function load($file) {
    include $file . '.php';
    echo $lang['word'];
    echo $lang['text'];
}
```

If you include the file outside the function then `$lang` will be `global` for the function and you can access this by using global keyword.

like:

```
include 'en.php';
function load() {
    global $lang;
    echo '<br>'.$lang['word'];
    echo '<br>'.$lang['text'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `global` declaration to make `$lang` a global variable:

```
function load($file) {
    global $lang;
    include $file . '.php';
    echo $lang['word'];
    echo $lang['text'];
}
```